# Java Matrix Rotation In place

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to create a program in Java that takes a NxN matrix and rotates it in place. I am implementing a method that takes each column and changes it to the row to do this. My stacks are correct and so are my loops as I have outputted them to check.

```
Stack<Integer> takeCol = new Stack();

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

    //take columns and make them rows (ROTATION METHOD)
    for (int j = matrix[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

        takeCol.push(matrix[j][i]);
    }

    //reverse stack
    Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack();
    while (!takeCol.isEmpty()) {

        temp.push(takeCol.pop());
    }

    //rotate matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

        matrix[i][j] = temp.pop();
    }
}
```

My temp stack is correct and so are i and j for the placements. However here is an example output:

Before Rotation:

```
3 9 8 2 
5 5 5 1 
4 7 6 4 
4 1 8 2
```

After rotation:

```
4 4 5 3 
1 7 5 4 
8 6 5 5 
2 5 4 3
```

FULL CODE:

public class Q1_7 {

```
public static void createMatrix(int matrix[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
        }
    }
}

public static void displayMatrix(int matrix[][]) {

    System.out.println("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");
}

public static void rotateMatrix(int matrix[][]) {

    Stack<Integer> takeCol = new Stack();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

        //take columns and make them rows (ROTATION METHOD)
        for (int j = matrix[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            takeCol.push(matrix[j][i]);
        }

        //reverse stack
        Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack();
        while (!takeCol.isEmpty()) {

            temp.push(takeCol.pop());
        }

        //rotate matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = temp.pop();
        }
    }
    displayMatrix(matrix);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter size of matrix to be rotated");
        int matrixSize = s.nextInt();
    //create matrix size of user input
    int matrix[][] = new int [matrixSize][matrixSize];

    createMatrix(matrix);
    displayMatrix(matrix);
    rotateMatrix(matrix);
    s.close();
}
```

}

Comment: @Makoto uploaded full code

Comment: well the 9 is disappeared? Maybe some values are left on the stack or they are overridden by other values?

Comment: @Daniele The stacks are perfect. Ive checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pretty lengthy answer below- I have added debug logs to your program so that it is easier to follow what is happening. The problem is, the code overrides values before they are rotated, so eg. 9 is overridden by 4 before being read. See code and logs below. (also note that adding logs helps to debug)

output is:

```
3 9 8 2 
5 5 5 1 
4 7 6 4 
4 1 8 2 


pushing num=[1] val=4
pushing num=[2] val=4
pushing num=[3] val=5
pushing num=[4] val=3
pushing temp num=[1] val=3
pushing temp num=[2] val=5
pushing temp num=[3] val=4
pushing temp num=[4] val=4
writing to m[0,0] val=4
writing to m[0,1] val=4    <-------- here: 9 is overridden by 4
writing to m[0,2] val=5
writing to m[0,3] val=3
pushing num=[5] val=1
pushing num=[6] val=7
pushing num=[7] val=5
pushing num=[8] val=4      <<----- here: we want 9 but is has been overridden 
pushing temp num=[5] val=4
pushing temp num=[6] val=5
pushing temp num=[7] val=7
pushing temp num=[8] val=1
writing to m[1,0] val=1
writing to m[1,1] val=7
writing to m[1,2] val=5
writing to m[1,3] val=4
pushing num=[9] val=8
pushing num=[10] val=6
pushing num=[11] val=5
pushing num=[12] val=5
pushing temp num=[9] val=5
pushing temp num=[10] val=5
pushing temp num=[11] val=6
pushing temp num=[12] val=8
writing to m[2,0] val=8
writing to m[2,1] val=6
writing to m[2,2] val=5
writing to m[2,3] val=5
pushing num=[13] val=2
pushing num=[14] val=5
pushing num=[15] val=4
pushing num=[16] val=3
pushing temp num=[13] val=3
pushing temp num=[14] val=4
pushing temp num=[15] val=5
pushing temp num=[16] val=2
writing to m[3,0] val=2
writing to m[3,1] val=5
writing to m[3,2] val=4
writing to m[3,3] val=3
4 4 5 3 
1 7 5 4 
8 6 5 5 
2 5 4 3
```

code is:

```
package sample;

import java.util.Stack;

public class A {

    void go(int[][] matrix) {

        Stack<Integer> takeCol = new Stack<>();

        int numPushTake=0;
        int numPushTemp=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

            //take columns and make them rows (ROTATION METHOD)
            for (int j = matrix[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

                int val = matrix[j][i];
                System.out.printf("pushing num=[%d] val=%d%n", ++numPushTake, val);
                takeCol.push(val);
            }

            //reverse stack
            Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack();
            while (!takeCol.isEmpty()) {

                int val = takeCol.pop();
                System.out.printf("pushing temp num=[%d] val=%d%n", ++numPushTemp, val);
                temp.push(val);
            }

            //rotate matrix
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

                int val = temp.pop();
                System.out.printf("writing to m[%d,%d] val=%d%n", i, j, val);
                matrix[i][j] = val;
            }
        }
    }

    void dump(int[][] m) {
        for (int i=0;i<m.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<m[i].length;j++)
                System.out.print(m[i][j]+" ");
            System.out.println("");
        }           
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A o = new A();
        int[][] matrix = {
                {3, 9, 8, 2 },
                {5, 5, 5, 1 },
                {4, 7, 6, 4 },
                {4, 1, 8, 2 }
        };
        o.dump(matrix);
        System.out.println("\n");
        o.go(matrix);
        o.dump(matrix);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is causing it to override that?

Comment: Looking at the logs, we see "writing to m[0,1] val=4", that is output on a certain line in the code. (can you look it up?)

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` is an interesting choice (challenge?). Note that you can do this in-place without any other data structures, with just using the 2D array.

Note also that you can compose right rotation from transpose and y-reflection primitives as well.

```
   int[][] matrix = {
            {0, 1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6, 7},
            {8, 9, 10, 11},
            {12, 13, 14, 15}
    };

    // ignoring validation steps ...

    // this is the transpose operation
    int n = matrix.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int t = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = t;
        }
    }

    // this is reflection on y-axis.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
            int t = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][n - j - 1];
            matrix[i][n - j - 1] = t;
        }
    }

    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```

will give

```
[12, 8, 4, 0]
[13, 9, 5, 1]
[14, 10, 6, 2]
[15, 11, 7, 3]
```

In addition to composing to building blocks, also using a deterministic input with distinct elements will help debugging if something goes wrong.

you can fuse the two loops into one but getting first a working implementation is very useful.